# VAT price will be 25% of product 'subtotal price and shipping price' instead of only 'subtotal price'

Tags: views, 7, commerce

I am working on a `Drupal commerce` site. Everything is working fine as per my requirement. But I have to modify some setting for `checkout preview page (price detail table)`.

Currently into the product detail price table, there are `shipping price` and `VAT price` are there and the `VAT` price is depends on `Subtotal` price. `I mean the VAT price ($75) is 25% of Subtotal price ($300)`.

Now I want to change `VAT price functionality`, means the VAT price will be 25% of sum of `'Subtotal price and shipping price'` (i.e. `$300 + $78 = $378`). So now the VAT price will be  `$94.5`.

and the sequence of the price type will be

```
1. Subtotal
2. Shipping
3. VAT
4. Order total
```

So how can I set VAT price 25% of 'Subtotal price and Shipping price'?
And How can I manage their sequence?

Recently the table is showing look like the attached screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah!, finally I got the answer of my question and now everything is working absolutely fine as per my requirement.

For this we just create a new `Rule` for this. Here is the exported code of my created `Rule`.

```
{ "rules_taxes_shipping" : {
"LABEL" : "Taxes Shipping",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"WEIGHT" : "9",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "Shipping", "taxes" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "commerce_tax", "commerce_shipping" ],
"ON" : { "commerce_shipping_calculate_rate" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "commerce_tax_calculate_by_type" : {
      "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce-line-item" ],
      "tax_type_name" : "vat"
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

And to rearrange the sequence of the price item just set `weight` for that particular item using `alter`, look like the below code.

```
function hook_commerce_price_formatted_components_alter(&$components, $price, $entity) {
  $components['flat_rate_shipping']['weight'] = 0;
  $components['tax|vat']['weight'] = 1;
}
```

This will set the sequence of this item.

```
1. Subtotal
2. Shipping
3. VAT
4. Order total
```